# How to close full screen baner ad from aerserv through code?

Tags: admob, inmobi

I am working on ad integration using aerserv ad monetization platform. I want to close full screen banner ad after some period of time line 5 seconds, How I can do it through code?

Answer (score 1):

You should not close the ads programmatically. It will be considered fraud if you do so and the Ad Source will stop showing ads on your app.